# Update SQL rows from another table and a static value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to create rows in a temporary table using values from another table as well as static values. The best I could come up with is this snipped of code, using multiple queries. I'm curious if there's a single SQL query that could achieve this.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users (user_id INT, location_id INT);
INSERT INTO temp_users (user_id) SELECT id FROM users WHERE user.role = 'employee';
UPDATE temp_users SET location_id = 11;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_users  AS
SELECT id user_id, 11 location_id  FROM users WHERE user.role = 'employee';
```

Comment: Defining the schema of the new table as we go along here is really, really clever. 

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you can mix the values in a single insert like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users (user_id INT, location_id INT);
INSERT INTO temp_users (user_id, location_id)
SELECT id, 11
FROM users
WHERE user.role = 'employee';
```

Comment: This is really great Amy, I can't believe something this useful wasn't already here in stack overflow (or if it is, it's not easy to find). I'm finding the INSERT INTO syntax here really useful for use with some tables that already existed.